# declare Angular2 component at top level module and use at lower level modules

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

I am working on Angular2 application using Angular2 final release.

[image]

This is my application scenario. I have a component which I want to use same component at two different modules at two different level.

If I declare it at FeatureModule and use it it works. And I haven't tried but if I export it from FeatureModule then it would work in main module as well.

But component i designed is not feature specific. So it doesn't seem right to declare it at FeatureModule level and then propagate to other levels. I think it would be more appropriate to declare at AppModule level or MainModule level and use it in both MainModule & FeatureModule level. But this doesnt work. It is throwing following error.

**If 'xxxx' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.**

Any idea, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your component in a separate module and have your Main and Feature modules import it.

Comment: I prefer this way. It seems more appropriate to me. Also @YariG answer is another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to declare it on bootstrapping in AppModule. Then you could use it app wide.